# Cascaded Router Network Addresses

Tags: networking, router

In my home network, I have to use AT&T's router. It is a Motorola NVG510.

Behind this router is my personal router, a dual band Netgear TL-WDR3500 with USB ports for my NAS drives.

The AT&T router connects to the DSL line, and has its wireless radios turned OFF.

- IPv4 Address: `192.168.1.254`
- Subnet Mask: `255.255.255.0`
- DHCPv4 Start: `192.168.1.64`
- DHCPv4 End: `192.168.1.253`

[image: AT&T Settings]

My Netgear router connects directly to one of the switches on the AT&T router.

- IP Address:   `192.168.0.1`
- Subnet Mask: `255.255.255.0`
- Default Gateway: `192.168.1.254`

[image: Netgear Router]

I want to setup the Cascaded Router feature, but to do that I need to supply the following:

- **Cascaded Router Address:** The IP address for the router behind this device. The Cascaded Router Address should be in the LAN Private IP subnet range.
- **Network Address:** The Network Address that defines the range of IP addresses available to clients of the cascaded router.
- **Subnet Mask:** The subnet mask that with the Network Address defines the range of IP addresses available to clients of the cascaded router.

Everything I try gets kicked out as invalid.

For the Cascaded Router Address, I always enter `192.168.0.1`, since that is the defined as the router address on my Netgear router. That only leaves Network Address and Subnet Mask.

Network Address `192.168.1.253`, for example, is rejected because it is not in the network address given subnet mask `255.255.255.248`.

I got Cisco certified in networks about 10 years ago, but I was never able to get a job in networks. I can't remember how I am supposed to calculate the network address ranges and subnet masks anymore.

Can someone give me this information? I would also like to know how to go about calculating these for my information, just in case something changes down the road.

Comment: This may have what I need: [AT&T Article: Configuring IP Passthrough](http://www.att.com/gen/general?pid=23697)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I got to work. (**Update:** see my comment below; this stopped working the next day.)

I had to configure the subnets. What worked for me was only allowing 1 IP address:

[image: Subnets]

Next, I had to configure the firewall to allow IP Passthrough:

[image: Passthrough]

At this point, I rebooted the AT&T router modem.

While that was going on, I used my wireless network card to configure my Netgear router. I had to change the IP address, Default Gateway and Primary DNS:

[image: att_netgear_settings]

By the time I was doing all of that, the Motorola router modem was through rebooting, and HERE I AM! :)

That was a lot of work for me!

Hopefully, someone comes along later and gets some good out of it.

Comment: OK, that worked great last night. Today, though, it does not work. It seems as though AT&T is no longer able to authenticate my account using the Motorola router, so I am stuck trying to find out how to "undo" these settings.

Answer (score 1):

Both routers need to be in the same subnet. In your case this would mean a range of `192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.7`. This means that your routers WAN IP has to be in this IP address range.

The detailed steps are explained here:

https://forums.att.com/t5/Features-and-How-To/How-to-put-the-Motorola-NVG589-in-bridge-mode-or-as-close-as-you/m-p/3552057#M39255

Otherwise, why not dual NAT and put any servers, NAS etc. into the outside one? My RPi makes for a decent VPN and NAS.

Comment: So, I can only issue out six (6) IP addresses? I have more devices than that in my network. How do I fix that?

Comment: As for your "otherwise" question: AT&T's router is all that AT&T's network will connect to. I have to use the one AT&T issues me. My account is bound to the MAC address of that device. AT&T's router is plain vanilla. It does not have any features.

Comment: The otherwise scenario seems to be working looking at your screenshots. The TP-Link has an IP address assigned from the AT&T router and performs NAT just fine. See the edited answer.

Comment: So, is **BRIDGE MODE** what the rest of the world calls these Motorola **Cascade Router** terms?

Comment: Yes it appears that the Cascade Router mode is less like a Bridge but more like a DMZ. https://forums.att.com/t5/Residential-Wi-Fi-Gateway/Motorola-NVG510-quot-Cascaded-Router-quot/td-p/3869499

Comment: From your description, I assume you have not purchased any static IP addresses. I hope that's answered everything!

Comment: I'm not really enough of a network professional to understand what you mean by dual NAT or what the statement about *"RPi makes for a decent VPN and NAS"* means. When I have both routers enabled, I have network connection issues every time a device attempts to renew it's IP address.